# Multiplying Multi Index Pandas Series and DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> Data=pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B'], data=[[20,40],[100,300]], columns=['Var1','Var2'])
>>> Data.index.name='ID1'
>>> Data
     Var1  Var2
ID1            
A      20    40
B     100   300
>>>
```

And I have the following series:

```
>>> MIndex=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A',1),('B',1),('A',2),('B',3)])
>>> MultSeries=pd.Series(index=MIndex, data=[.6,.7,.4,.3])
>>> MultSeries.index.names=['ID1','ID2']
>>> MultSeries.name='MultFactor'
>>> MultSeries
ID1  ID2
A    1      0.6
B    1      0.7
A    2      0.4
B    3      0.3
Name: MultFactor, dtype: float64
>>>
```

I want to multiply each element in the series by the appropriate element in the series.

Right now I can do that by converting the series to a dataframe and then joining:

```
>>> d1=pd.DataFrame(MultSeries).join(Data)
>>> d1[['Var1','Var2']].multiply(d1['MultFactor'],axis=0)
         Var1  Var2
ID1 ID2            
A   1      12    24
B   1      70   210
A   2       8    16
B   3      30    90
>>>
```

Is this the best way to do this? Is there a way to do it without having to use the join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with parameter `level`:

```
In [83]: Data.mul(MultSeries, axis=0, level='ID1')
Out[83]: 
         Var1  Var2
ID1 ID2            
A   1      12    24
B   1      70   210
A   2       8    16
B   3      30    90
```