# Multiply each value in DataFrame cell according to multi-index name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Given this pandas Dataframe

```
list_index = pd.Series(['A' for i in range(2)] + ['B' for i in range(4)] + ['C' for i in range(3)] + ['D' for i in range(6)], name='indexes')
list_type = pd.Series(['a', 'c'] + ['a', 'b','c','d'] + ['f','g','i'] + ['a','c','d','e','f','g'], name='types')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
}, index=[list_index, list_type])

indexes types   value
A       a       1
        c       2
B       a       3
        b       4
        c       5
        d       6
C       f       7
        g       8
        i       9
D       a       10
        c       11
        d       12
        e       13
        f       14
        g       15
```

I want to multiply each value by a factor (aka ratio) contained in another pandas.Dataframe

```
ratio_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ratio' : [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]
}, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

    ratio
A   0.1
B   0.2
C   0.4
D   0.5
```

So that all values in `df` with 'indexes' == 'A' are multiplied by 0.1, and values with 'indexes' == 'B' are multiplied by 0.2 and so on.
I'm sure there is some smart way to do that but right now I can't really think of it. I know I can 'expand' ratio_df to the same length of df (with reset_index() and then creating a new column for df including ratios) and than simply perform `*` operation pairwise, but I'm not sure that's the fastest method.

I also looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516509/multiplying-multi-index-pandas-series-and-dataframe) but it's slightly different from my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If just needing the product of the two columns [Series.mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) can be aligned based on index level.

Just select the columns and `mul` on index level:

```
df['value'].mul(ratio_df['ratio'], level='indexes')
```

or with index level number:

```
df['value'].mul(ratio_df['ratio'], level=0)
```

The result is an unnamed Series:

```
indexes  types
A        a        0.1
         c        0.2
B        a        0.6
         b        0.8
         c        1.0
         d        1.2
C        f        2.8
         g        3.2
         i        3.6
D        a        5.0
         c        5.5
         d        6.0
         e        6.5
         f        7.0
         g        7.5
dtype: float64
```

---

The resulting Series can be assigned back to `df` as needed:

```
df['new'] = df['value'].mul(ratio_df['ratio'], level='indexes')
```

`df`:

```
               value  new
indexes types            
A       a          1  0.1
        c          2  0.2
B       a          3  0.6
        b          4  0.8
        c          5  1.0
        d          6  1.2
C       f          7  2.8
        g          8  3.2
        i          9  3.6
D       a         10  5.0
        c         11  5.5
        d         12  6.0
        e         13  6.5
        f         14  7.0
        g         15  7.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename the `ratio` column to `value` then use `mul` on `level=0`:

```
df.mul(ratio_df.rename(columns={'ratio': 'value'}), level=0)
```

Result

```
               value
indexes types       
A       a        0.1
        c        0.2
B       a        0.6
        b        0.8
        c        1.0
        d        1.2
C       f        2.8
        g        3.2
        i        3.6
D       a        5.0
        c        5.5
        d        6.0
        e        6.5
        f        7.0
        g        7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way resetting only first level; `join`ing; `multiply`ing and `set_index` back to original:

```
out = df.reset_index(level=1).join(ratio_df).assign(New=lambda x: x['value']*x['ratio']).set_index('types', append=True)
```

Output:

```
         value  ratio  New
  types                   
A a          1    0.1  0.1
  c          2    0.1  0.2
B a          3    0.2  0.6
  b          4    0.2  0.8
  c          5    0.2  1.0
  d          6    0.2  1.2
C f          7    0.4  2.8
  g          8    0.4  3.2
  i          9    0.4  3.6
D a         10    0.5  5.0
  c         11    0.5  5.5
  d         12    0.5  6.0
  e         13    0.5  6.5
  f         14    0.5  7.0
  g         15    0.5  7.5
```